# Started Learning Automation and need help for infrastructure

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am a manual tester and am learning automation testing and using Selenium web driver with python to create test for web project. Currently I am writing test in python using eclipse and run from eclipse only.

Do i need to setup a testing framework to run test automatically? If yes, which is best suited testing framework for these tools and what I do need to learn to setup testing framework?
How can i track my test runs and test results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good example of testing infrastructure with WebDriver and Python is at Mozilla.

- They use `py.test` as testing framework with special plugin `pytest-mozwebqa` - https://github.com/davehunt/pytest-mozwebqa.
- There have templates for writing tests - https://github.com/mozilla/mozwebqa-test-templates.
- An example of project is https://github.com/mozilla/Addon-Tests.
- They use Jenkins for continuous integration - https://jenkins.mozilla.org.

Comment: all the above mentioned project repo's are in inactive state